# Calculating sum formula in c++

Tags: c++

I am having trouble rewriting this question into c++. This is what I've came up so far. I think I am missunderstanding the question. What am I doing wrong?

Calculating sum formula:

[image]

```
double sum(double n) {
    double formula = (n/n+1);
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
      formula += i;
    }
    return formula;
}

int main()
{   
    double n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << sum(n);
}
```

Comment: The formula is a sum of fractions, so why are you instead summing the natural integers?

Comment: What question? Are you saying you misunderstand the algorithm or the code? If you don't understand the algorithm, then there's no point in trying the code yet.

Comment: `n/n+1` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: `n/n+1` is always 2 unless n is 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should works

```
double sum(double n) {
    double formula = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        formula += double(i)/double((i+1));
    return formula;
}
```

Comment: You need to typecast I to float, 1/2 will give output 0

Comment: I think you have misunderstood not the coding part of this problem, but the basic fractions rules

Comment: Is it? Run this code: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 cout<<1/2;
 return 0;
}

Comment: And...I see you did the changes.....

Comment: The parameter type should probably be changed to `int`, and the extra `( )` in `double((i+1))` can be removed.

Comment: What do you mean parameter type needs to be changed to int, because if I do so, I keep getting answer 0.

Comment: @brahski You're doing something wrong then: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T5b7rc

Comment: okay, I can rewrite it to working form, but I believe, that author's concern isn't caused by cpp programing skills, but rather knowledge of fraction rules.

Comment: `formula += double(i)/double((i+1))` can be written in a much more readable way as `formula += i/(i + 1.0)`